# Add gridline upto line height from x-axis in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have created line chart and I want to customize the chart by adding the grid lines from the x-axis to the point(if possible) using d3.js or any other suggestion on how to add is helpful. My graph currently is like
[image]

It should look like

[image: this]

Sample code

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width - (margin.left + margin.right)]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - (margin.top * 2), 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.module); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data = [
    {"value": 83, "module": 0},
    {"value": 79, "module": 1},
    { "value": 73, "module": 3},
    {"value": 71, "module": 4},
    {"value": 67, "module": 5},
    {"value": 65, "module":6}
]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.value = +d.value;
      d.module = +d.module;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.module; }));
    y.domain([
      (Math.floor(d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }) / 10) * 10),
      (Math.ceil(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; }) / 10) * 10)
    ]);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((margin.left + margin.right) / 2) + "," + (height - margin.top) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
            .ticks(6)
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return 'Module ' + d; })
        )

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
```

You can look through my code in the code editor [here](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/ZEYNLYz)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width - (margin.left + margin.right)]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - (margin.top * 2), 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.module); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data = [
    {"value": 83, "module": 0},
    {"value": 79, "module": 1},
    { "value": 73, "module": 3},
    {"value": 71, "module": 4},
    {"value": 67, "module": 5},
    {"value": 65, "module":6}
]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.value = +d.value;
      d.module = +d.module;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.module; }));
    y.domain([
      (Math.floor(d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }) / 10) * 10),
      (Math.ceil(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; }) / 10) * 10)
    ]);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((margin.left + margin.right) / 2) + "," + (height - margin.top) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
          .ticks(6)
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return 'Module ' + d; })
        )

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  
  
  
    // Data line and dots group
    var lineAndDots = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "line-and-dots")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((margin.left + margin.right) / 2) + "," + 0 + ")")

    // Data line
    lineAndDots.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "data-line")
        .attr("d", line);

    // Data dots
    lineAndDots.selectAll("line-circle")
      .data(data)
     .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "data-circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.module); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
        
    g.selectAll("lines-ax")
      .data(data)
     .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.module) + margin.right + 10; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return height - margin.bottom })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.module) + margin.right + 10; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3);
        
        
        /*focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

        //focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));*/
```

```css
body {  
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;  
}
  
.axis {
 font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  
text {
  fill: #727075;
  stroke: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke: none;
}

.grid line {
  stroke: #E0E0E0;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
  
.data-line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #3C92BA;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
  
.data-circle {
 fill: #3C92BA;     
}
  
.axis-title {
 text-anchor: end;
  fill: #5D6971;
  font-weight: normal;
}
  
.axis-tspan {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="730" height="375"></svg>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I want to fill each of the spaces with different colors. How should I add? @mamoun othman

Comment: @SPL, will check it today, once I have time